# Does Spring require all beans to have a default constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, default-constructor

I don't want to create a default constructor for my `auditRecord` class.

But Spring seems to insist on it:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'auditRecord' defined in ServletContext resource
[/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
Instantiation of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [com.bartholem.AuditRecord]: 
No default constructor found; 
nested exception is 
java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
com.bartholem.AuditRecord
```

Is this really necessary?

Comment: Please show your config that loads the bean - XML or annotations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272543/no-default-constructor-found-nested-exception-is-java-lang-nosuchmethodexceptio

Answer (score 34):

No, you are not required to use default (no arg) constructors.

How did you define your bean?  It sounds like you may have told Spring to instantiate your bean something like one of these:

```
<bean id="AuditRecord" class="com.bartholem.AuditRecord"/>

<bean id="AnotherAuditRecord" class="com.bartholem.AuditRecord">
  <property name="someProperty" val="someVal"/>
</bean>
```

Where you did not provide a constructor argument.  The previous will use default (or no arg) constructors.  If you want to use a constructor that takes in arguments, you need to specify them with the `constructor-arg` element like so:

```
<bean id="AnotherAuditRecord" class="com.bartholem.AuditRecord">
  <constructor-arg val="someVal"/>
</bean>
```

If you want to reference another bean in your application context, you can do it using the `ref` attribute of the `constructor-arg` element rather than the `val` attribute.

```
<bean id="AnotherAuditRecord" class="com.bartholem.AuditRecord">
  <constructor-arg ref="AnotherBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="AnotherBean" class="some.other.Class" />
```

Answer (score 20):

nicholas' answer is right on the money for XML configuration. I'd just like to point out that when using annotations to configure your beans, it's not only simpler to do constructor injection, it's a much more natural way to do it:

```
class Foo {
    private SomeDependency someDependency;
    private OtherDependency otherDependency;

    @Autowired
    public Foo(SomeDependency someDependency, OtherDependency otherDependency) {
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
        this.otherDependency = otherDependency;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a little problem with that. This annotation works in one part of the application, but in test I get a 'no no-argument constructor' error. Could you please tell if there is a way to solve that without injecting arguments or adding a default constructor?

Comment: @JohnDoe: You need to ask a new question rather than posting a comment to a really old answer. Also, if that's all there is to your question, you're not going to get a good answer. Include stack traces and example code as appropriate to demonstrate your problem. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). See also [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do constructor based injection, i.e. something like this (taken from documentation found [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection))

```
<bean id="foo" class="x.y.Foo">
    <constructor-arg ref="bar"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="baz"/>
</bean>
```

but I'm not sure it will work.

If you are defining a JavaBean, you need to follow the convention and put a public no-arg constructor on it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all Java developers know that compiler adds a default constructor or better known as a no-argument constructor in every Java class, but many of them forget that it only does when you don't provide any other constructor. This means it becomes the developers' responsibility to add a no-argument constructor if he is adding explicit constructor. Now, Why it's important to provide default constructor in Java, What happens if your class doesn't have a no-argument constructor? Well, this is how it's asked in many Java interviews, most commonly as part of Spring and Hibernate interviews.

You should always define a no argument constructor in your Java class, even if you are writing an explicitly constructor, until you are absolutely sure that, it's won't be instantiated using reflection and instantiating it with no argument constructor is a bug, like in your example of Spring Bean.