# Scala with Spring: Constructor autowiring

Tags: spring, scala, constructor, autowired

I'm looking for "idiomatic" way to autowire Scala classes with Spring through constructor injection.
I've tried something like this:

```
   @Component
   class MyService @Autowired() ( val myDao: MyDao) extends Logging {
   ...
   }
```

But I get an error:
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [MyService]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: MyService.()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:964) ~[spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]

Comment: Are you sure you are not instantiating `MyService` manually? Please add how is `MyService` instantiated in your application. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7492652/1333025

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've added support for @Autowired on the constructor of a Scala object into the spring-scala project. This is only (at time of writing) in the nightly snapshot.

This allows you to do

```
@Component
@Autowired
class Service(dep : Dependency) { }
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-scala

Comment: Cool! Looking forward for release!

Comment: Eagerly waiting for release :) .

Answer (score 0):

We use this style for a Spring MVC app:

```
  @Component
  class MyService extends Logging {

    @Autowired
    private val myDao: MyDao = null

  }
```

Comment: Yes, I know this way, but it is not as Scala-ish as it should be :)

Comment: If you want to do it in a Scala-ish way then don't use spring ;) ... we've been converting away from this style as fast as possible.