# No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working with Spring MVC controller project. Below is my Controller and I have a constructor declared which I am specifically using for testing purpose.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    private static KeeperClient testClient = null;

    static {

    // some code here

    }

    /**
     * Added specifically for unit testing purpose.
     * 
     * @param testClient
     */
    public TestController(KeeperClient testClient) {
        TestController.testClient = testClient;
    }

    // some method here

}
```

Whenever I am starting the server, I am getting below exception -

```
No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
```

But if I remove `TestController` constructor then it works fine without any problem. What wrong I am doing here?

But if I add this default constructor then it starts working fine -

```
    public TestController() {

    }
```

Comment: You need to add a no-args constructor to have @Controller work. `public TestController() {}` .When you remove your custom constructor, the default constructor (no args) becomes available, but in the presence of a constructor with args, a no-args constructor is not implicitly present.

Comment: @TJ yes it works fine after adding that but before I didn't have any default constructor, just now I added the constructor with parameters then it started failing.

Comment: Add another constructor with no-args. You can have multiple constructors. `Polymorphism`. A default no-args constructor is implicit in the absence of explicitly defined constructors.

Comment: This is simple Java: if you do not have any constructors, then a default no-argument constructor will be created for you. Once you created your own constructor, it's your responsibility to create a default one (if needed). Since Java Bean requires a default constructor you get your error.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to define *no-args* or *default* constructor if you are creating your own constructor.

You can read why default or no argument constructor is required here:
[Why default or no argument constructor is important in Java class?](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/01/why-default-or-no-argument-constructor-java-class.html)

Comment: i'm also getting this error, but i cannot add a default constructor since i'm using a class which is from jar file.
Class name : FormDataContentDisposition,
jar file : jersey,
how to avoid this issue??

Comment: @NibrasSameeh let me know if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113406/no-default-constructor-found-exception

Comment: thanks for the reply, that question has been asked by my self, still i haven't got the correct answer yet.

Answer (score 57):

Spring cannot instantiate your TestController because its only constructor requires a parameter. You can add a no-arg constructor or you add @Autowired annotation to the constructor:

```
@Autowired
public TestController(KeeperClient testClient) {
    TestController.testClient = testClient;
}
```

In this case, you are explicitly telling Spring to search the application context for a KeeperClient bean and inject it  when instantiating the TestControlller.

Comment: The same applies when using `@Value` annotation in constructor. Spring simply needs to know you want to inject something.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, spring threw this because i forgot to make an inner class static.

When you found that it doesnt help even adding a no-arg constructor, please check your modifier.

Comment: Had the same problem - I just simply moved the class up.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I forgot to add `@RequestBody` annotation to the method argument:

```
public TestController(@RequestBody KeeperClient testClient) {
        TestController.testClient = testClient;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is using **both** Guice and Spring and using the constructor @Inject, for example, with Play Framework, you will also run into this issue if you have mistakenly auto-completed the import with an incorrect choice of:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
```

Then you get the same `missing default constructor` error even though the rest of your source with @Inject looks exactly the same way as other working components in your project and compile without an error.

Correct that with:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
```

Do not write a default constructor with construction time injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.
First, let's declare the static variable we want to inject NAME_STATIC.
Afterward, we'll create a setter method, called setNameStatic and annotate it with the @Value annotation:
@RestController
public class PropertyController {

```
@Value("${name}")
private String name;

private static String NAME_STATIC;

@Value("${name}")
public void setNameStatic(String name){
    PropertyController.NAME_STATIC = name;
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).