# Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I tried for Configuration with MvcConfiguration.java as Dispatcher file.But it throw errors while creating bean for controller and DAO file.

I know there are lots of question regarding this error on stackoverflow.
But I'm not able to solve and stuck in it.

Following are files in which I found below errors.

**EmployeeController.java**

```
package com.jwt.controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.jwt.model.Employee;
import com.jwt.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

    public EmployeeController() {
        System.out.println("EmployeeController()");
    }

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView listEmployee(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Employee> listEmployee = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
        model.addObject("listEmployee", listEmployee);
        model.setViewName("home");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addObject("employee", employee);
        model.setViewName("EmployeeForm");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee) {
        if (employee.getId() == 0) { // if employee id is 0 then creating the
            // employee other updating the employee
            employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
        } else {
            employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int employeeId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(employeeId);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int employeeId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployee(employeeId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("EmployeeForm");
        model.addObject("employee", employee);

        return model;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE project PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0 dtd">
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jwt.spring</groupId>

<artifactId>SpringMVCHibernateCRUD</artifactId>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>SpringMVCHibernateCRUD Maven Webapp</name>

<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<!-- Specifying the Versions of Spring, Hiberante, MySQL etc -->

<properties>
<spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
<mssql.version>4.0</mssql.version>
<junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
<servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>
<jsp-version>2.2.1</jsp-version>
<jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
<java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
<version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate 4 dependencies -->

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
<version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!--MSSQL Connector -->

<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Servlet and JSP --> 

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- JSTL dependency -->


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->



<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JUnit -->



<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.11</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
<finalName>SpringMVCHibernateCRUD</finalName>
<plugins>


<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>


<configuration>


<includes>

<include>**/*Tests.java</include>

</includes>

</configuration>

</plugin>


<plugin>

<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.3.2</version>


<configuration>
<source>${java.version}</source>
<target>${java.version}</target>
</configuration>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>

</project>
```

**MvcConfiguration.java**

```
package com.jwt;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.jwt.controller.EmployeeController;
import com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl;

import javafx.scene.control.Alert;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.jwt")
@EnableWebMvc

public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    public void demo() {
        System.out.println("in configuration...");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        System.out.println("in configuration...");
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;

    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        System.out.println("in datasoure");
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");      
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433\\MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=Demo");
        dataSource.setUsername("gcflex_user");
        dataSource.setPassword("Gcas1234!");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeeDAO getContactDAO() {
        return new EmployeeDAOImpl(getDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeeController getEmployeeController() {
        return new EmployeeController();

    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Hibernate CRUD Example</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value> org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.jwt.MvcConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

**EDIT :-**

EmployeeService.java

```
package com.jwt.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.jwt.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeService {

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee);

    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees();

    public void deleteEmployee(Integer employeeId);

    public Employee getEmployee(int employeeid);

    public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee);
}
```

EmployeeServiceImpl.java

```
package com.jwt.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.jwt.model.Employee;

@Service
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employeeDAO.addEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteEmployee(Integer employeeId) {
        employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(employeeId);
    }

    public Employee getEmployee(int empid) {
        return employeeDAO.getEmployee(empid);
    }

    public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return employeeDAO.updateEmployee(employee);
    }

    public void setEmployeeDAO(EmployeeDAO employeeDAO) {
        this.employeeDAO = employeeDAO;
    }

}
```

**Error Log :-**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'employeeController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.jwt.service.EmployeeService
>   com.jwt.controller.EmployeeController.employeeService; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAO
>   com.jwt.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDAO; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'employeeDAOImpl' defined in file [D:\Macron
>   Workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVCHibernateCRUD\WEB-INF\classes\com\jwt\dao\EmployeeDAOImpl.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl]: No default constructor
>   found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.()  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5362)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) 
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.jwt.service.EmployeeService
>   com.jwt.controller.EmployeeController.employeeService; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAO
>   com.jwt.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDAO; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'employeeDAOImpl' defined in file [D:\Macron
>   Workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVCHibernateCRUD\WEB-INF\classes\com\jwt\dao\EmployeeDAOImpl.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl]: No default constructor
>   found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.()  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>   ... 29 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAO
>   com.jwt.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDAO; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'employeeDAOImpl' defined in file [D:\Macron
>   Workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVCHibernateCRUD\WEB-INF\classes\com\jwt\dao\EmployeeDAOImpl.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl]: No default constructor
>   found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.()  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)

Comment: "Failed to instantiate [com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException" ... that's plain and simple English, what is unclear about that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException with Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272543/no-default-constructor-found-nested-exception-is-java-lang-nosuchmethodexceptio)

Comment: Can you add your EmployeeService implementation as well here?

Comment: @gohil90. Yeah I just edited my question with EmployeeService implementation please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be keep it simple.

1. Remove below bean creation from configuration class -

> ```
> @Bean
> public EmployeeDAO getContactDAO() {
>     return new EmployeeDAOImpl(getDataSource());
> }
>
> @Bean
> public EmployeeController getEmployeeController() {
>     return new EmployeeController();
> }
> ```

2. Annotate controller class with @Controller, service with @Service & DAO with @Repository. Then, you can easily autowire them in other class.

> ```
> @Repository
> public class EmployeeDAOImpl {
> }
>
> @Service
> public class EmployeeService {  
>     @Autowired
>     private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
> }
>
> @Controller
> public class EmployeeController {
>     @Autowired
>     private EmployeeService employeeService;
> }
> ```

3. Lastly, for your EmployeeDAOImpl class, remove any parameterized constructor you have for datasource. You can simply autowire that too as you have created @Bean for datasource in configuration file -

> ```
> @Bean
> public DataSource datasource() {
>     System.out.println("in datasoure");
>     return dataSource;
> }
>
> @Repository
> public class EmployeeDAOImpl {
>     @Autowired
>     private Datasource datasource;
>
> }
> ```

This way your issue should get fixed.

Comment: @Bhavin sure. Let me know if you stuck somewhere. And mark my answer correct if it works. Cheers :)

Comment: @Bhavin Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;
```

This is the issue. I see a dependency for EmployeeService in your controller implementation, but you did not paste the EmployeeService class definition here. Does this class exist and is there a bean being defined for it? The controller bean is expecting this bean to be injected by Spring, but Spring is not able to find it in the application context, since it does not exist, and hence the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Saharsh. Yeah it's exist and I have updated my question with it please check it.

Comment: Ah, didn't dig deep enough in the stack trace. The DAO class may actually be the issue:

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.jwt.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.()

Comment: Your suggestion also worked for me. Thank you for your help.