# spring force fields initialization

Tags: java, spring

How can we translate the following object into a spring bean so that we may keep the exact functionality? By functionality I am trying to focus on the constructor initialization.

```
class RealObject {
    private String f1;
    private String f2;
    private String f3;
    private int f4;
    private int f5;

    public RealObject(String f1, String f2, String f3, int f4, int f5) {
        this.f1 = f1;
        this.f2 = f2;
        this.f3 = f3;
        this.f4 = f4;
        this.f5 = f5;
    }

    ... getters ...
}
```

A spring bean will look like

```
@Bean
class RealObject {
    private String f1;
    private String f2;
    private String f3;
    private int f4;
    private int f5;

    ... getters ...
}
```

The problem with this bean is that it will never force me to give the parameters I need in my object. I can do some manual checkings for each of the inputs but if you have too many... It won't be elegant at all.

What solutions do I have?

Later edit: I need to pass the values at runtime.

Comment: [Potential duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492652)?

Comment: Because you use Spring (or whatever DI solution) doesn't mean everything has to be a managed bean. Why would you need that class to be managed by spring?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Autowired` and `@Value` together on the constructor

```
@Autowired
public RealObject(@Value("#{property.f1}") String f1, 
                  @Value("#{property.f2}") String f2, 
                  ... ) {

}
```

In this case you need an external properties to assign values to `f1`, `f2`...

Comment: I do not want to get the values from properties. I need to somehow pass them at runtime.

Comment: You can't with strings. You can create an object that contains all this strings and inject that object.

Comment: Additionally. If you need to pass them at runtime, why you need to instantiate the object via spring?

Comment: I need to inject a service inside the object and I still need to set a few things (like an init function).